# Navigating through a program with enums

Tags: java, enums, public

My question is rather simple. My user starts off in public enum EntranceState. If my user enters 1 to enter the house I am attempting to send the user to next enum "HouseState". I attempted to call upon it as if it were a void but it is not working any suggestions?

```
public class LAB{

public  enum EntranceState {IN_LIVINGROOM, OUTSIDE_HOUSE} {
    EntranceState state = EntranceState.OUTSIDE_HOUSE;
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to enter house enter 2 to stay outside");
        int action = get();
        if (action == 1) {
            state = EntranceState.IN_LIVINGROOM;
        }
            else if(action == 2){
                state = EntranceState.OUTSIDE_HOUSE;

            }
        if(state == EntranceState.IN_LIVINGROOM ){

        HouseState{IN_BED1};//Attempting to send my user to the second enum
        }
    }


public static int get(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int action = input.nextInt();

    return action;
}
public void start(){

}

    public enum HouseState{IN_BED1} {
        System.out.println("Enter 1  to enter bedroom 1, Enter 2 to enter bedroom 2, Enter 3 to enter garage Enter 4 to stay in living room");
    }

public static void main(String [] args){
    LAB l = new LAB();
    l.start();

}
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to build a state machine and assign a variable, not use multiple enums

Comment: I think you need to read up on program flow in Java.  Currently your main() just calls start() on a new Lab, which literally does nothing.

Comment: What is actually not working? And what's expected result?

Comment: So if the user chooses the state IN_LIVINGROOM, i wish to send the user to the next enum HouseState where he can make more decisions. @IvanPronin

Comment: `public  enum EntranceState {IN_LIVINGROOM, OUTSIDE_HOUSE} {` probably does not do what you think it does. It creates an enum with two members, but the code after it is an [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) that runs when an instance of the class is created (in this case, when you call `new LAB()`). It's not part of the enum at all. The code probably belongs in a method, anyway, you can't "send a user to the enum" like it's a method to be run.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder thanks for your help